# How to create a file of unique database records with a One to One relationship in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have many tables that have a One to One relationship with a table Client, mapped by Hibernate.

I need to create a file of unique Clients after a select on each of these tables using threads.

Each of these tables (such as Invoice, Service etc) will also be included in the file, but AFTER the list of clients (government requirement, don't ask why...).

I've thought of 3 different ways to do this:

**Method 1: Using a HashSet**

I add the Client objects to a HashSet after each select. Sadly, this solution is not scalable, as table B could have millions of unique records and could result in an OutOfMemory error.

**Method 2: Using a view**

I could also create a view joining the tables. The problem is that these selects have many complex rules and are subject to frequent changes. Maintenance would be a nightmare as it would require me to change the program and the view.

**Method 3: Using temporary tables**

I could create a temporary table to store Client objects found in each of the tables, then perform a select on that table.

Method 3 seems to be, so far, the best solution, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. How can I improve my design?

Comment: Method 3 looks fine for me. Another method is some distributed cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the problem with the wrong perspective.

I was fixated on selecting the database and creating different files (i.e one for Invoices, one for Services etc) during each of the threads, and then joining all of the files into a single one. That's one solution of course, but it raises the problem above.

A second way of doing this is simply selecting the records on the database first (threads and all). Then, the file can be created using a Template engine (such as FreeMarker, Chunk...) or a custom formatter.

There are many ways of doing this with threads (even though the run() method returnsa void):

- Using an ExecutorService with a FutureTask to get a list of the models;
- Using a static Object with synchronized methods to hold the models;
- Using dependency injection to inject said object on the Runnable object, making it a Singleton.